# how to get name of guest who have bought two things

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, sqlite

how should i get the data from the table where the guest has bought two things ...

```
     select TA.orderid as ORDERID,custid,name,description,ITEMID from 

 (
 select T3.custid as CUSTID,orderid,name from 
  (
 select orderid,custid from orders
 ) as T3

 inner join 
(select custid, name from customers)as T4

 on T3.custid=T4.custid
  order by name
)as TA

inner join 

( 
 select T1.itemID as ITEMID, OrderID,description from 
 (
select itemID,OrderID from ItemsOrdered
)as T1

inner join 
(
select itemID, description from Items
)as    T2
 on T1.itemID=T2.itemID

)as RA

on TA.orderid=RA.orderid
```

what i am trying to achieve is to get the list of customers who have bought exactly two items.

[image]

a nudge to the right direction would be really helpfull

Comment: Two things, or at least two things?

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a nudge I'd look into using something like aggregate functions along with the `GROUP` and `HAVING` SQL qualifiers. For example, something like:

```
SELECT custid FROM custorder GROUP BY custid HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

would return just the list of IDs for customers who have two purchases from the table you list above, assuming its name were `custorder`. Obviously if that's the result of a join operation you'll need to replace the `custorder` with that `JOIN`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, @Feneric, your contribution might cause the questioner more trouble than it solved, as you proffered a query that identifies guests who brought MORE THAN ONE item, not EXACTLY TWO items.

How 'bout this'n:

```
SELECT   custid  
FROM     custorder  
GROUP    BY custid  
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: I answered before the comment stating exactly two was posted. Edited to reflect the comment.